# Adding a featured image to a foreach Wordpress loop

Tags: loop

I just found a clever piece of code on line which allows Wordpress posts to be displayed in side by side columns and works great with the title and post excerpt that I want to display.

However I would like also to display a specific featured image that I defined in the functions file in each post. Here is the code that works fine apart from a lack of output for the featured image. I'm guessing my syntax is incorrect at that point.

```
                <?php
                    // Custom loop that adds a clearing class to the first item in each row
                    $args = array('numberposts' => -1, 'order' => 'ASC', 'post_type' => 'treatments' ); //For this example I am setting the arguments to return all posts in reverse chronological order. Odds are this will be a different query for your project
                    $allposts = get_posts($args);
                    $numCol = 2; // Set number of columns

                    // Start Counter
                    $counter = 0;
                    foreach ($allposts as $post) {
                        $content = '<div class="six columns'.' '.($counter % $numCol == 0 ? ' alpha' : 'omega').'">'; // Add class to the columns depending on if it is odd or even
                        $content .= '<section class="treatments lightgrey-background">';
                        $content .= '<figure>';
                        $content .= '<img src="'.($post->the_post_thumbnail->small).'" />';
                        $content .= '</figure>';
                        $content .= '<h4>'.$post->post_title.'</h4>';
                        $content .= $post->post_excerpt;
                        $content .= '</section>';
                        $content .= '</div>';
                        echo $content;
                        $counter ++;
                    }
                ?>
```

I'd like a fallback image if the user hasnt specified a featured image too. I'd guess an if else statement similar to the short hand used to add a class to the columns would be appropriate? Here is the featured image code that is in the functions file.

```
<?php
// add featured image
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 120, 120, true );
add_image_size( 'small', 120, 120, true );
add_image_size( 'medium', 330, 330, true );
add_image_size( 'front_page', 460, 350, true);
add_image_size( 'header', 660, 200, true);
add_image_size( 'large', 600, 390, true );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax problem:

```
$content .= '<img src="'.($post->the_post_thumbnail->small).'" />';
```

The `the_post_thumbnail()` function is not part of the `$post` object, and would *print*, rather than *return*, the post thumbnail, even if that method would work.

Try using **`get_the_post_thumbnail()`** instead:

```
$thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'small' );
```

Note that this function returns the fully formed `<img>` tag markup, so you would need to adapt your code accordingly:

```
$content .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'small' );
```

### Edit

Note that `'small'` is an image size already defined by WordPress, so you'll want to use a different name. I would use something location-descriptive, such as `'post-two-column'`:

```
add_image_size( 'post-two-column', 120, 120, true );
```

Then, reference accordingly in your loop:

```
$content .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-two-column' );
```

Comment: Perfect that is just what I needed thankyou!